# Bokeh integration with CSS and jinja

Tags: python, css, jinja2, bokeh

I have a bokeh dashboard which needs some custom styling(CSS).
I'm relatively new to the bokeh library and from what I understand, I need to use a jinja2 template wherein I can specify the CSS.

The dashboard has a 4 level hierarchy and the lower level plots only show up on selection at the level above. The hierarchy is as follows-

1. Dropdown(widget) - This is the only thing shown on first load
2. Plot 1(shows/updates on change of dropdown)
3. Plot 2 (shows/updates on selection in plot 1)
4. Plot 3 (shows/updates on selection in plot 2)

My index.html looks something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sales Performance Analysis</title>
    <link *CDN Links*>
    <script *CDN Links*</script>
    {{ script }}
</head>
<body class="bk-body">
    <h1>Sales Performance Analysis</h1>
    {{ div }}
</body>
</html>
```

In my main.py, I have the following lines of code at the end to render-

```
script, div_plot = components(curdoc())
curdoc().template_variables["script"] = script
curdoc().template_variables["div"] = div_plot
```

When I execute this as a server app (bokeh serve --show *folder_name*), the browser application shows the dropdown widget but nothing happens on changing the values.

The same thing runs perfectly when run in standalone mode as bokeh serve --show *main.py*

Would appreciate any kind of pointers.
TIA

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `bokeh.embed.server_session` instead of `bokeh.embed.components` (which only statically embed the document)

Here's the reference:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#bokeh-applications

Comment: Thanks Luke. I'm trying out the autoload_server.

Comment: Since I want to render my complete document, I'm not passing any arguments to autoload_server

Follow up question - How do I utilize the script returned by autoload in my jinja2 template? Currently, I have a placeholder in the template - {{ script }} and I assign it the value of autoload script using curdoc().template_variables["script"] = script

But now the application loads up showing only the <title> element from my template.

Comment: Since I want to render my complete document, I'm not passing any arguments to autoload_server

Follow up question - How do I utilize the script returned by autoload in my jinja2 template? Currently, I have a placeholder in the template - {{ script }} and I assign it the value of autoload script using curdoc().template_variables["script"] = script

But now the application loads up showing only the <title> element from my template.

Comment: Just realized.. I can directly copy the autoload script in my html template. Gonna try this now

Comment: you may have to add a {{ script | safe }} flag so that your JS script isn't escaped.

Comment: Thanks @Luke. The autoload_server recommendation worked for me.